# Self is treated as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

While passing the parameters mp_neuron.fit(), it asks for a third parameter.

Can anyone explain why self is not being recognized

[image]

Comment: Next time please add the code itself instead of using images

Answer (score 1):

You haven't new a object for `MPNeuron`, it should be

```
mp_neuron = MPNeuron()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating the object.

```
mp_neuron = MPNeuron
```

This should be

```
mp_neuron = MPNeuron()
```